# unable to create android client socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to create an android client app that connects to a server on my desktop.
I successfully telneted to the server from my laptop.
I have put INTERNET and NETWORK permissions in manifest file.
The program crashes when creating the socket and eclipse debuuger gets me to socket.class source file.

**UPDATE:**
here's my complete code

```
public class EsmFamilActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_esm_famil);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.esm_famil, menu);
    return true;
}

//handler for sendtoserver
public void sendToServer(View view){

    ...


    String host = "192.168.1.7";
    int port = 8888;
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        out.write(data + "\n");
        out.flush();
        s.close();
    }catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

and here is my logcat

```
01-18 21:43:06.908: D/TextView(1608): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
01-18 21:43:09.658: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1608): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-18 21:43:09.668: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1608): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-18 21:43:11.448: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1608): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-18 21:43:11.448: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1608): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-18 21:43:46.018: D/AndroidRuntime(1608): Shutting down VM
01-18 21:43:46.018: W/dalvikvm(1608): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42f02500)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3678)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4300)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18026)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3673)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     ... 11 more
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.example.myfirstapp.EsmFamilActivity.sendToServer(EsmFamilActivity.java:61)
01-18 21:43:46.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     ... 14 more
01-18 21:43:53.518: I/Process(1608): Sending signal. PID: 1608 SIG: 9
01-18 21:43:53.668: D/TextView(2467): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
01-18 21:43:53.668: W/ResourceType(2467): Skipping entry 0x1060085 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-18 21:43:53.668: D/TextView(2467): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
01-18 21:43:53.668: D/TextView(2467): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
01-18 21:43:53.998: D/libEGL(2467): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
01-18 21:43:54.078: D/libEGL(2467): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
01-18 21:43:54.088: D/libEGL(2467): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
01-18 21:43:54.088: E/IMGSRV(2467): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 42
01-18 21:43:54.098: E/IMGSRV(2467): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 45
01-18 21:43:54.098: E/IMGSRV(2467): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
01-18 21:43:54.098: E/IMGSRV(2467): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
01-18 21:43:54.098: E/IMGSRV(2467): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
01-18 21:43:54.108: E/IMGSRV(2467): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 48
01-18 21:43:54.138: D/OpenGLRenderer(2467): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: "_The program crashes_" What error messages are you getting? Post your logcat.

Comment: Look up [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask) you're getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: You are right noloader, my question is a duplicate of the question you mentioned. I couldn't find the OnMainThreadException in the logcat. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that the android app is running in the emulator on the server desktop. So first of all you need to change that LAN IP 192.168.x.x

> Blockquote When working with the Android emulator, you may frequently need to access data
> hosted on the local web server using localhost. For example, your own web services
> are likely to be hosted on your local computer during development, and you’ll
> want to test them on the same development machine you use to write your Android
> applications. In such cases, you should use the special IP address of 10.0.2.2 (not
> 127.0.0.1) to refer to the host computer’s loopback interface. From the Android
> emulator’s perspective, localhost (127.0.0.1) refers to its own loopback interface.

## cited from http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-android-application-development-631/

Then if the android app is not in running in the server I guess you need some extra lines to avoid errors:

```
serverAddress =
InetAddress.getByName(“192.168.1.142”);
//--remember to change the IP address above to match your own-- and also the port
socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 500);
```

And also I'm asumming you're doing inside the extends AsyncTask class.

Comment: No i am running the app from my asus fonepad tablet connected to my desktop. I have tested using InetAddress but it didn't work.